# designing the database if depending on dynamic columns

Tags: database-design

In my project,"admin" can create text fields dynamically (using jsp +javascript) and enter can enter data in text fields for saving.in the back end i have to save them in database.
here the problem is

**1)how we can create columns dynamically depending on the textfields admin is creating.
like if he is creating 5textfields then we should create 5 columns in database,if he going with 10 we should do 10 columns.**

im doing this in mysql,jsp,struts,hibernate

Comment: When the admin comes up with a brand new column name, does that represent a brand new addition to the conceptual data model?  Is it a new attribute?  If the answer is "yes", how do you plan to make sense out of the resulting database?  Are you planning on analyzing the semantics of the data at retrieval time?  Lotsa luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a relational store then these are optimised for variable rows not columns. ie. think about putting the variable number in rows rather than columns.

My suggestion is simply to have a header table + a details table.

Then header is a (1) and the details are the many and variable. Then all you need is 4 columns in the details

```
detail_id (pk), header_id (fk), detail_item_no, detail_value
```

and the header

```
header_id (pk), .. any other items that are in all types...
```

and add as many rows as you like for for each header row. If you need 10 then detail_item_no goes from 1 to 10, if you need 5 then detail_item_no goes from 1 to 5

The downside is that the query to get the details is slightly more complex as it involves a simple join rather than a simple select.

OTOH if you now there is only ever going to be 20 columns then simply create a table with that number of columns and leave the unused ones unused.